# Upper bound on the bisectional curvature

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, kahler-ricci-flow

This is a follow-up to the question [Schwarz lemma and bisectional curvature lower bound](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412683/schwarz-lemma-and-bisectional-curvature-lower-bound/412688?noredirect=1#comment1060593_412688). Looking at the same note [Song and Weinkove - Lecture notes on the Kähler–Ricci flow](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.3653), page 24, the first line reads:

If $C_N$ is an upper bound for the bisectional curvature of $g_N$ we see that $g^{l \bar k}g^{\bar j i}S_{\alpha \bar \beta \gamma \bar \delta}f^{\alpha}_{i} f^{\bar \beta}_{\bar j} f^{\gamma}_{k} f^{\bar \delta}_{\bar l} \leq C_{N} (\text{tr}_{\omega} f^{\ast}\omega_{N})$.

Using the same logic as explained in the [accepted answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/412688) of [Schwarz lemma and bisectional curvature lower bound](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412683/schwarz-lemma-and-bisectional-curvature-lower-bound), we want to consider $$ C_{N} = \sup _{x \in M} \inf \{ S (e_i, \bar {e_i}, e_j, \bar {e_j}) \mid \{e_1, \bar {e_1}, \dotsc, e_n, \bar {e_n} \} \text{ is orthornormal w.r.t. } g \text{ at } x, \ i, j = 1, \dotsc, n\} \ .$$

However, now $g$ is the evolving Kähler–Ricci flow. Is it still true that the orthonormal frames with respect to all of the Kähler–Ricci flow are compact so that $C_{N}$ is finite? Also on the right hand side of the inequality there is $\omega_{N}$ but it does not even appear on the left hand side. Why?

Comment: any comments or thoughts?